# Is it a bad idea to allow mulitple ways to get a product on a site?

Tags: seo, google, search-engines

I am building a site where we will sell products etc. Currently the url to get to a product is like so "Store/Store_product_page/The product_ID" or "Store/Store_product_page/The product_title"

I have been doing some SEO on the site and I am not sure if it matters if there is multiple ways to get to a product page. Should I have just one way or the other but not both ways to get to the same product page?

Also does it matter much if I just made it so only this way worked "Store/Store_product_page/The product_ID"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much better practice to have the one destination accessible from different areas of the site. If you had for example `store/productpage/theproduct` and from wherever you place the product it was just to use this link then you avoid copied content and there is no need to redirect. If the pages have been indexed though then you may want to follow the previous commenter's option of 301 and `rel="canonical"`.

Answer (score 1):

If two URLs are indexed by Google, it most probably considers that two URLs imply a duplicate content issue and it can penalize SEO of your two pages.

A good way to avoid this is to implement 301 redirect from one URL to the other or use the `rel="canonical"` tag on one URL.

Read the [Google support page on duplicate content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, Never new about the canonical tag, thanks for the link too. It seems it is OK for two different links to the same page as long as you use the canonical tag to tell search engines the preferred link to use.

Answer (score 0):

Two URLs should not target the same page. It is consider as duplicate. Make it one page by using 301 redirection. It's far better to use words in URLs when possible, otherwise there may be a chance for making mistakes in development and testing.